# Array FormData can't be read in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

I have problem in regards with Array of Objects inside the form data but couldn't read in ASP.NET web api.

I don't know why after sending the data to the api it wont get me anything it in the list and has 0 count of them.  Is anyone having the same issue or did I miss somewhere on either in react or asp.net?

**JSON Format**

```json
Other: "Other1",
Other2: "Other2",
Another: 1,
Datas: [
 {
   Id: 1,
   Name: "name1"
 },
 {
   Id: 2,
   Name: "name2"
 }
]
```

**React**

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Other", body.Other);
formdata.append("Other2", body.Other2);
formData.append("Another", body.Another);
body.Datas.map((data, i) => {
   formData.append(`Datas[${i}].Id`, data.Id);
   formData.append(`Datas[${i}].Name`, data.Name);
})

axios.post(`url`, formData); // sending data to the web api
```

**Controller**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostIdsAndNames([FromForm] PostedData data) // here is the problem
{
   // can get data from the Other, Other2, Another but nothing on the list.
   // list is 0 or data is null for some reason
}
```

**Model**

```cs
public class PostedData
{
    public string Other { get; set; }
    public string Other2 { get; set; }
    public int Another { get; set; }
    public List<Data> Datas { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `axious` should be axios

Comment: `Datas` or `Data` ? The names are different. Is this a typo in the question or an actual bug in the code? BTW why post form data instead of a JSON object? The typo will affect both though.

Comment: Datas wait lemme change

Comment: @SinanYaman can you explain to me why?

Comment: Because it is the name of the library :D

Comment: my bad but axios is working perfectly and able to capture the data in the web api, though the list is the problem because the lists couldn't read for some reason when sending to asp.net web api.

Comment: @AlvinQuezon I suspect you should clean up the code first, and post actual code that reproduces the problem. Until now there were two serious errors that would prevent the code from working. We can't guess what else may be missing

Comment: Do you mean `axious.post` is working?

Comment: changed the name to proper one sorry misspelled

Comment: If `axious.post` is working it means that either you aren't using `axios`, or you aliased when you imported it, probably due to a typo, eg `const axious = require('axios');
`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I just skipped the import part for the `axios` library since it went through the web api when  doing a `post` request, my only concern is that it couldn't capture the list `Datas` to the web api for some reason.

Comment: [This article by Scott Hansleman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/aspnet-wire-format-for-model-binding-to-arrays-lists-collections-dictionaries) explains how form binding works for arrays. The data you posted should work. Perhaps `Datas` should be a `Data[]`? What does the *actual* POST body look like?

Comment: You can speed up testing a lot if you inspect the POST request in the browser's Dev tools and reissue the same request either from the Dev tools or POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

It's syntax should be like this.

```
axios({
method: "post",
url: "myurl",
data: bodyFormData
})
.then(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
});
```